# Error when updating App Info

Tags: windows-phone, marketplace

I get this error when I try to update xap and App Info (not when uploading):

*Couldn't upload app 

 We couldn't save your info at this time. Try again later.*

On "Submission Errors and Warnings" I get the error:
 *Market price: Include at least one distribution market*

Problem appears when I try to change App Info and it has something to do with market selection: 
When I manually try to select even one market I get the first error again.
When I select "Distribute to all markets except those with stricter content rules" I get the second error.
When I select "Distribute to all available markets at the base price tier" I get the first error

Uploading of the xap went smooth. I discovered this problem 24 hours ago.

**EDIT:**
Deleting and resubmitting seems to be a solution but you can't touch App Info! Selecting for example "Distribute to all markets except those with stricter content rules" reproduce the above behavior....

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I wonder if the service is actually down and the are doing a poor job of letting us know what the issue is (as per usual on the Marketplace).

Comment: Could have been a temporary issue. I was not able to reproduce this.

Comment: This Problem is only due to some site down issue!

Comment: Please contact our marketplace support. This is not something that can be solved on StackOverflow.